# Implementing CSP (Communicating Sequential Processes) in Scala

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I am trying to implement a parser and semantic for a 'CSP' in Scala .  I have already implemented the parser , and now I am busy working on a Semantic part of the language. I am completely new to the world of concurrent systems and non-deterministic choices. so here is my question:

I want to implement the "Non-deterministic Choice" and "Interface Parallel"  as explained 
[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes#Informal_description).

I now can understand understand the procedure but I can't get my head straight when it comes to non-determinism. I am in need of a good data type to implement this in Scala, I am thinking to put all the processes in a list and then randomize the list and then choose a element from modified list. but that doesn't sound so non-deterministic for me.

Has anyone experienced on this issue before and knows a good algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

My very limited understanding of CSP is that the CSP operators correspond to the following Haskell types:

```
-- Prefixing corresponds to functions
x :: A
P :: B
x -> P :: A -> C

-- Choice corresponds to product
P :: A
Q :: B
P □ Q :: (A, B)

-- Non-determinism corresponds to sum
-- I don't know how to make the non-determinism symbol, so I use (△)
P :: A
Q :: B
(P △ B) :: Either A B
```

Then you can use the algebraic isomorphisms to reduce CSP expressions.  Using the Wikipedia example:

```
(coin -> STOP) □ (card -> STOP)

-- translates to the following Haskell type:
(coin -> Stop, card Stop)

-- which is algebraically isomorphic to:
(Either coin card -> Stop)

-- translates in reverse back to CSP:
coin □ card -> STOP
```

Also, I think one of the Wikipedia examples is wrong (or I'm wrong).  I believe this expression should reduce to:

```
(a -> a -> STOP) □ (a -> b -> STOP)

-- translates to the following Haskell type:
(a -> a -> STOP, a -> b -> STOP)

-- which is algebraically isomorphic to:
a -> Either a b -> STOP

-- translates in reverse back to CSP:
a -> (a △ b) -> STOP
```

I still haven't figured out the equivalent of interface parallel, though.  It doesn't seem to correspond to an elegant concept.

Answer (score 1):

This is an advanced topic. The parsing side is the easy bit. Writing correct concurrent primitives is *very* hard and will almost certainly require formal verification using a tool such as FDR.

If you're only interested in writing the expression parser part, not the concurrency primitives, you might prefer to build upon [**JCSP**](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/jcsp/), which already provides these primitives in a Java API. The authors of this (UKC) used formal verification to validate its components, notably the channel and alternative (choice) parts.